# Creating the "About" dialog

Tags: vala

I know i have to use `Granite.Widgets.AboutDialog` but how do i create it so it looks exactly like the Noise about dialog?

I can't find how the About dialogue is created in Noise source code.

Any help/pointers welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The about dialog is part of granite
http://valadoc.org/#!api=granite/Granite.Widgets.AboutDialog

The content is filled in the class that is subclassing `Granite.Application`

http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~elementary-apps/noise/freya/view/head:/src/Noise.vala

Then the about dialog can be launched with `"name of you binary" --about`

http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~elementary-apps/noise/freya/view/head:/data/noise.desktop